# pass Database Mail parameters to stored prcedure using php and sql server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters

I want to use Database mail for my application and this means I need to pass parameters to the stored procedure `sp_send_dbmail` 
I have the following code just for testing purposes. I however want to know how to pass Parameters to a stored procedure using ssql server 2008 and php.
FYI I am using sqlsrv driver from Microsoft

```
<?php require_once ('../Connection/connmail.php')?> 
<?php
 $sql = "{CALL sp_send_dbmail[[@profile_name='gmailsmtp']]}";//my stored procedure

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql)or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));    


 ?>
```

The above code produces the error

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '{'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '{'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 105 [code] => 105 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '[@profile_name='gmailsmtp']}'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '[@profile_name='gmailsmtp']}'. ) )
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this was unanswered for a while so here is the solution. Make your user a `databasemailuserrole` in the msdb system database

```
$callmailproc = "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = ?, @recipients=?, @subject=?, @body=?";
$profilename = 'DatabaseMail';
$recipients = 'recipient@domain.com';
$subject='Test Message';
$body = 'This is the body';
$params = array( 
                 array($profilename, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                 array($recipients, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                 array($subject, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                 array($body, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                 );

/* Execute the query. */
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $callmailproc, $params);
if( $stmt3 === false )
{
     echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```